# Merge two revisions of file to different branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a file `a.c` in the branch `branch_1` with below versions.

```
Previous version: 10
Next version : 20
Current version :25
```

My working copy is `branch_2`

I want to merge the difference between versions `20` and `10` in `branch_1` to working copy only for `a.c` file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pure SVN-way

<strike>Use 2-URL-merge and PEG-revisions</strike>Bottom example ["merge changes to a single file"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/merge/)

```
svn merge -c 20 ^/branch1/a.c a.c
```